# git submodule functionality with sibling?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project consisting of a library and various applications:

```
foo/
foolib/
bar/
baz/
qux/foo/
```

All of the applications link against *foolib*, a static library.

I would like *git commit* on *foo* to record the SHA1 ID of where *foolib* was at, and also *git status* on *foo* to report if there are uncommitted changes in *foolib*.

However I do not want to move *foolib* to having a copy of it as a subdirectory of every application. As well as being bloaty, this would lose the ability to try out some changes to *foolib* in multiple applications without committing the changes.

I have tried making a .gitmodules file that points to ../foolib but it seems to be completely ignored by *git status*.  I also tried making *foolib* a softlink inside *foo*, but *git* seemed to treat the softlink as a file instead of following the link.

Is what I want possible, or do you have any alternative workflow solutions?

On my public repository, the structure is the same, and each application (and foolib) has been cloned individually from the public.

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to create *another* repo `fooProject`, which would **declare as submodules**:

- `foo`
- `foolib`

(If you call your parent project `appProjects` instead of `fooProject`, you could declare as submodules all the sub-directories: `foo`, `foolib`, `bar`, `baz`, ...)

If any of the sub-directories (`foo` or `foolib`) changes and makes a new commit, you go back to the parent repo and commit as well, in order to record the SHA1 of the different submodules.